# Get text contained within the parentheses at the end of string

Tags: php, regex

Say I have this user list:

```
Michael (43)
Peter (1) (143)
Peter (2) (144)
Daniel (12)
```

The number in the furthest right set of parentheses is the user number.

I want to loop each user and get the highest user number in the list, which in this case would be `144`.
How do I do this? I'm sure it can be done with some kind of regexp, but I have no idea how. My loop is simple:

```
$currentUserNO = 0;

foreach ($users as $user) {
    $userNO = $user->NameUserNo; // NameUserNo is the string to be stripped! ex: "Peter (2) (144)" => 144

    if ($userNO > $currentUserNO) {
        $currentUserNO = $userNO;
    }
}

echo "The next user will be added with the user number: " . $currentUserNO + 1;
```

Comment: And where is your regex?

Comment: @revo "I'm sure it can be done with some kind of regexp, **but I have no idea how**."

Comment: @scrowler He may have no idea "how" to do it, but may have any idea to "try"!

Comment: @revo this is StackOverflow though...

Comment: How is `NameUserNo` generated in the 1st place? The answer should probably involve modifying the user class, not in some regex hack

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a regex like:

```
/\((\d+)\)$/
          ^ glued to the end of the string
        ^^ closing parentheses
    ^^^ the number you want to capture
 ^^ opening parentheses
```

to capture the number in the last set of parentheses / at the end of the string.

But you could also use some basic array and string functions:

```
$parts = explode('(', trim($user->NameUserNo, ' )'));
$number = end($parts);
```

which breaks down to:

- trim the closing parentheses and spaces from the end (strictly speaking from the beginning and end, you could also use `rtrim()`);
- explode on the opening parentheses;
- get the last element of the resulting array.

Comment: accepted for the basic array trick and +1 for the explanation of the regexp :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are not confortable with regular expression you should not use them (and start to seriously learn them* as they are very powerful but cryptic).

In the mean time you don't have to use regex to solve your problem, just use (assuming that the NameUserNo contains just a line of the list) :

```
$userNO = substr(end(explode('(',$user->NameUserNo;)),0,-1);
```

It should be easier to understand.

* [Is there a good, online, interactive regex tutorial?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/476714/is-there-a-good-online-interactive-regex-tutorial)

Comment: Why tell people *not* to use regular expressions? The way to get more comfortable with them is to use them! Too many people think that regexs are scary, strange things (particularly in PHP, where there is also a misconception that they are hideously slow), but they are just another tool in the programmer's toolbox.

Comment: @ialarmedalien Think of this: Peoples think regexp are scary just because the go on stackoverflow (or similar sites), ask for a regular expression that solve their current problem and copy and paste it. This is not the way to learn regex or make them less scary.

Comment: @Eineki that is a problem with SO in general: people asking questions who are looking to plug a particular hole in their program, and people answering questions who post code with no explanation. Not much that can be done about the former, but the latter can be combatted by adding explanatory text for solutions. I've also found, coming from a Perl background, that PHP users are much less comfortable with regexs--the first code I wrote in Perl used regexs for file parsing! If more PHP programmers were introduced to regexs earlier, there would not be this aura of danger and mystery around them.

Comment: @ialarmedalien regexs in php were hisotrically a bit chaotic. Two flavours of regexs were supported: the extended posix ones (ereg*), now deprecated, and the perl ones (preg*). Imagine a php newbie, struggling with this. Add that Usually the standard php newbie does not have previous programming experience and draw your sums.

With this I do not want to say that they are lost to the regular expression mastering but that they have to take a tutorial or study the language in a more organized way than asking for advice when needed. Hence the link to the tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

I think the regular expression you are looking for is:

```
.+\((\d+)\)$
```

Which should select all characters until it reaches the last number wrapped in parenthesis.

The PHP code you can use to extract just the number is then:

```
$userNO = preg_replace('/.+\((\d+)\)$/', '$1', $user);
```

I haven't tested this, but it should set `$userNO` to `43` for the user `Michael` and `143` for the user `Peter` and so on.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is basically what you are looking for:

```
<?php
$list = array();
foreach $users as $user) {
  preg_match('/$([a-zA-Z]+).*\([1-9]+\)$/', , $tokens);
  $list[$tokens[2]] = $tokens[1];
}
ksort($list);
$highest = last(array_keys($list));

echo "The next user will be added with the user number: " . $highest++;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty easy to do with a regex.

```
foreach ($users as $user) {
    # search for any characters then a number in brackets
    # the match will be in $matches[1]
    preg_match("/.+\((\d+)\)/", $user->NameUserNo, $matches);
    $userNO = $matches[1];
    if ($userNO > $currentUserNO) {
        $currentUserNO = $userNO;
    }
}
```

Because regexs use greedy matching, the `.+`, which means search for one or more characters, will grab up as much of the input string as it can before it reaches the number in brackets.

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly new to PHP, but couldn't you do it with:

```
$exploded = explode(" ", $user->NameUserNumber);
$userNo = substr(end($exploded), 1,-1);
```